# how to use limit in django rest framework generics.RetrieveAPIView

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

As generics.RetrieveAPIView in django rest framework should return only one record, i would like to use a limit in get query method like given below

```
class PortUserView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    lookup_field = 'user'

    def get_queryset(self):

        return PortUser.objects.all()[:1]
```

getting error like this "**Cannot filter a query once a slice has been taken**".

whats is wrong with my code?

Comment: I don't understand why you do that this way. The URL related to your view should contain a `<pk>` parameter that is the key of the object to retrieve. Redefining `get_queryset` should not be necessary. You can use [ModelViewSet](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset) and a [router](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/) that will generate the URLs for you.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There is no need for you to worry about returning a single object from the queryset at the time of `retrieve`. **DRF will handle that automatically** for you using its `.get_object()` defined in the [GenericAPIView](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#genericapiview).

You can just use the below code and DRF will handle the `retrieve` action for you.

```
class PortUserView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    lookup_field = 'user'
    queryset = PortUser.objects.all()
```

> get_object(self)
>
> Returns an object instance that should be used for detail views.
>   Defaults to using the lookup_field parameter to filter the base
>   queryset.

Source code for `retrieve` action:

```
def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    instance = self.get_object() # here the object is retrieved
    serializer = self.get_serializer(instance)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

We can see that DRF uses the `.get_object()` function to get the object from the queryset. To perform the filtering, it uses the `lookup_field` defined in the view.

Here is the actual `get_object()` code to make things more clear.

```
def get_object(self):
        """
        Returns the object the view is displaying.

        You may want to override this if you need to provide non-standard
        queryset lookups.  Eg if objects are referenced using multiple
        keyword arguments in the url conf.
        """
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())

        # Perform the lookup filtering.
        lookup_url_kwarg = self.lookup_url_kwarg or self.lookup_field

        assert lookup_url_kwarg in self.kwargs, (
            'Expected view %s to be called with a URL keyword argument '
            'named "%s". Fix your URL conf, or set the `.lookup_field` '
            'attribute on the view correctly.' %
            (self.__class__.__name__, lookup_url_kwarg)
        )

        filter_kwargs = {self.lookup_field: self.kwargs[lookup_url_kwarg]}
        obj = get_object_or_404(queryset, **filter_kwargs) # <-- can see that filtering is performed on the base of 'lookup_field'

        # May raise a permission denied
        self.check_object_permissions(self.request, obj)

        return obj # will return the single retrieved object
```

Comment: Now i am getting **"Original exception text was: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'age'."** though i have the "age" attribute in the PortUser Model.

after overriding 



`def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = self.get_object()  # here the object is retrieved
        serializer = self.get_serializer(instance, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
`


problem was solved but it is returning a list of JSON. But i don't want a list.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the code which you tried. It seems you did `<Queryset_object>.age` somewhere which would be wrong. `instance.age` would be valid as `age` is an attribute on `PortUserModel`. In `list` requests,a list of serialized objects would be returned and in `retrieve` requests, a serialized object in form of a dictionary would be returned.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to do this. Instead you should let the framework filter your queryset:

```
class PortUserView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset =  PortUser.objects.all()
```

Comment: Yes that's correct and the `lookup_field` must be added like in the edited snippet in the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
def get_object(self):
    queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
    lookup_url_kwarg = self.lookup_url_kwarg or self.lookup_field

    assert lookup_url_kwarg in self.kwargs, (
        'Expected view %s to be called with a URL keyword argument '
        'named "%s". Fix your URL conf, or set the `.lookup_field` '
        'attribute on the view correctly.' %
        (self.__class__.__name__, lookup_url_kwarg)
    )
    filter_kwargs = {self.lookup_field: self.kwargs[lookup_url_kwarg]}

    # ##########################################################################################
    # obj = get_object_or_404(queryset, **filter_kwargs)

    queryset = _get_queryset(queryset)
    try:
        return queryset.get(**filter_kwargs)
    except AttributeError:
        klass__name = queryset.__name__ if isinstance(queryset, type) else queryset.__class__.__name__
        raise ValueError(
            "First argument to get_object_or_404() must be a Model, Manager, "
            "or QuerySet, not '%s'." % klass__name
        )
    except queryset.model.DoesNotExist:
        res = {"success": "false", "code": 404, "message": 'Product Not found'}
        raise CustomValidation(res, 404)
        # raise Http404('No %s matches the given query.' % queryset.model._meta.object_name)

    # ##########################################################################################
    # May raise a permission denied

    self.check_object_permissions(self.request, obj)
    return obj
```

Answer (score 0):

`RetrieveAPIView` by default returns a single object. If multiple objects are returned, it would raise an exception. You just need to define queryset in you view.

```
class PortUserView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    lookup_field = 'user'
    queryset = PortUser.objects.all()
    url_kwarg = 'whatever_field_you_want_to_map'
```

Try to map the the `lookup_field` to a unique field in your model so that `MultipleObjectsReturned` exception is not raised inside the view.